# Looping through cells in a defined row in Excel

Tags: c#, excel, loops, rows

I have a for loop in C# that should loop through cells in column A and should check if the value of the cell is null. If the value isn't null, it should move to the next row and check. If the value of the cell is null, then it should write todays date in there. The problem now is, that my loop stops in the middle and gives the wrong row.

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application xlApp;
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook;
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet;
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range xlRange;

            object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

            xlApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
            xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(OpenExcel.FileName);
            
            xlWorkSheet = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);

            xlRange = xlWorkSheet.UsedRange;
            int currentRow;
            for (int i = 12; i <= xlRange.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                  
                if (xlRange.Cells[i,1].Value == null)
                {
                    xlWorkSheet.Cells[i,1] = DateTime.Now.Date;
                    currentRow = i;
                    break;
                }
                
            }
```

The loop should start in row 12 and should move from there. In my excel file, I can see that currentRow should be 20 when it's done but it keeps giving me 16.

I also have a picture of my excel file:
[Rows of my Excel file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yFjmA.png)

What do I need to change? Thanks in advance

Could it be that I really have to specify what sheet I wanna use? Because i have different sheets in my excel file.

[image: Here are my sheets]

Here is my column A. As you can see I want it to start at row 12
[image: Here is my column A. As you can see I want it to start at row 12]

Comment: ``` if (xlRange.Cells[i,1].Value2 == null)``` i think problem is here, ```Value2``` please check the value if it comes properly...

Comment: Thank you for your help. I tried using value instead of value2 but it still doesnt work

Comment: You should show how you compute x1Range. It could be anything!

Comment: Okay I will change my question to show it

Comment: Since you got the range of used rows, you have to start with 1(or 2, row 11 not shown) , not 12, i think. Furthermore you are looping through cells in a column.

Comment: Why do I need to start with 1?

Comment: @Turo I edited my question so now you can see my column and my rows

Comment: I think the index is relative to the range, not beginning of the sheet, i.e. range = 9-19(Datum!), rows.Count = 11, but you should check that, I'm not working with c#

Comment: @Turo Im not that good with c# i dont really know how to change the range to a set range

Comment: Just check with some debugging (console output of content) whicjk row you really have with index i